# Installed ocrmypdf, but cmd cannot find the variable

Tags: ocrmypdf

I am using Windows 11 and have installed OCRmyPDF using the tutorial: https://ocrmypdf.readthedocs.io/en/v12.0.1/installation.html#native-windows

It works when using it from Python, but when I try just using it via the command line, the computer throws the error: "The command ocrmypdf cannot be found". (No idea how the English error is, I am using a German system.)

So, clearly the PATH is not set - but I also do not know what to set the PATH to. Help?